# plus or dash at perm bits?

Tags: bash, permissions

When I need to find all files with SUID recursively starting from root directory I can do it in two not so different ways:

> find / -perm -4000

and the second one:

> find / -perm +4000

Which variant is preferable and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are 2 different ways of searching. `perm` allows for 3 methods:

1. `-perm mode`: permission bits set for the file are **exactly** that to match the search
2. `-perm -mode`: **all** of the permission bits are set for the file to match the search
3. `-perm +mode`: **any** of the permission bits are set for the file to match the search

So using - or + depends on what you want to find.

Examples:

`find / -type f -perm 0777` will find all files set as rwxrwxrwx (owner, group AND other)

`find / -type f +perm 0777` will find all files set as rwx for owner rwx for group OR rwx for other

Btw... it looks like the `+` is a the same as a '/`.

Comment: Can you explain 'any' case?

Comment: I'll add in some examples.